# Difference in query result in Serverless SQL Pool versus Apache Spark Pool

Tags: sql, azure, apache-spark, azure-synapse

For some reason the following query gives me different results in the Serverless SQL pool and the apache spark pool in azure synapse.

```
SELECT DISTINCT a.description, b.description, c.description
        FROM main_table as main
        LEFT JOIN (
                    SELECT DISTINCT key_1, key_2, key_3, key_4, key_5, foreign_key_table_b, foreign_key_table_c, description
                    FROM table_a
                   ) a
        ON main.key_1 = a.key_1 AND main.key_2 = a.key_2 AND main.key_3 = a.key_3 AND main.key_4 = a.key_4 AND main.key_5 = a.key_5
        LEFT JOIN table_b as b ON main.key_1 = b.key_1 AND main.key_2 = b.key_2 AND main.key_3 = b.key_3 AND a.foreign_key_table_b = b.foreign_key_table_b
        LEFT JOIN table_c as c on main.key_1 = c.key_1 and main.key_2 = c.key_2 and main.key_3 = c.key_3 AND main.key_6 = c.key_6 AND a.foreign_key_table_c = c.foreign_key_table_c
```

I need to join `table_a` to be able to join table_a with `main` first, for me to be able to join `table_b` and `table_c`, as `table_a` contains the foreign keys for `table_b` and `table_c`

Does anyone know what causes the difference in results? Is there some kind of join precedence, or NULL-handling that differs between the serverless SQL pool and the Apache Spark Pool?

Comment: If you have null values, try using coalesce(main.key_1,'')=coalesce(a.key_1,'')  on matching conditions

Comment: What does this do?